# encryption on the server side (using java) and decryption on the client side(using any javascript crypto library)

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, cryptography, sjcl

I want to decrypt the data on the client side which is coming from the server side encrypted with java (using asymmetric key), but i do not  have any idea that how it will work? do i need to use some jar or something on the server side ? what methods will be used what parameters needs to be supplied ? basically i don't know from where to start?

can any one provide me any idea or any working demo or any link how and from where to start this?

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You Most decrypt  data from server side before sent it .

Comment: please elaborate , i didn't get you.